# Errors-in-variables with correlated latent variable

Tags: regularization, errors-in-variables

Suppose I have data generated as follows:
$\tilde{X} = k \cdot X + u$, where X is an unobserved latent variable (say the temperature of the room) and X_tilda is the observed variable (say temperature as seen on a thermostat). k is a scaling factor and u is measurement error. But k is a known function of the variance of u and of the variance of X (say $k=\frac{Var(X)}{Var(X)+Var(u)}$).

If I observe $\tilde{X}$ and k, how do I construct a minimize least-squares error predictor of X? I have tried to derive it in the spirit of a James-Stein shrinkage but am stuck on the fact that k is a function of the variances of X and u.

Comment: I'm having a difficult time understanding how such a process could arise, I have to confess.  Your temperature example doesn't seem to work for me; why should the thermostat consistently be biased low, with the bias decreasing for rooms with more variable temperatures?  Also, what does $\sigma^2_X$ represent - the variance of the temperature over a day?  over a month?

Comment: @jbowman for example if the thermostat itself does some kind of Bayesian updating in reporting the temperature with prior 0. Then the updating process itself is correlated with the measurement noise, which is the idea here. $\sigma_{x}^{2}$ is the variance of temperature over some historical time period (so can think of as variance on the prior).